# Intent ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED is called whereas ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED is not

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to perform some code when an app is added or removed. I register a broadcast receiver and define an intent filter as follows:

```
    mMyReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    intentFilter.setPriority(999);
    registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, intentFilter);
```

As stated in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html I can even register ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED in my AndroidManifest. Well, when I uninstall an app ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED is called as well as ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED which is registered in my manifest file. However, when I install an app ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED is not called. I can't find no reason why. It's the same for all the other package related actions. The only ones I can get to work are those related to uninstallation. I really hope someone else has any sugestions on how to get it fixed. Thanks a lot!

Addition: On another device not even the PACKAGE_REMOVED and PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED intents are called. However, one out of 20 installations fired the ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED intent. Absolutely weird behaviour. And yes, the activity that's used to register the receivers is always running, so the broadcasts are not unregistered at any time. Is there something causing those intents not always to be called, I mean like one out of 20 times?

Addition 2: got my hands on a third device. Seems like all devices running android 11 (the first and the third device) run ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED and ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED without problems. But they never run ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED. The second device, however, runs android 10. It never calls any of the REMOVED actions but it does call the ADDED action one out of 20 times. I'm not 100% sure if the API version causes those different behaviours but the shit is getting trickier. I'm happy about any comment!

Addition 3: it's getting crazy. Yet another Android 10 device works perfectly fine and receives all PACKAGE related intens. How is such inconsistent behaviour even possible?

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solution to this problem. Because I am also facing the same issue and have also tried the listener for package added but that also didn't help.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I haven't. I'm surprised that this problem seems not to have been reported more often. Anyway, I must admit that I haven't investigated it any further.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me.

```
    var packageAddedReceiver = PackageAddedReceiver()

    val filter = IntentFilter()

    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
    filter.addDataScheme("package")
    requireContext().registerReceiver(packageAddedReceiver, filter)
```

and in Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.PackageAddedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The mistake I was making was registering my receiver with instead just using requireContext().registerReceiver(packageAddedReceiver, filter)

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireActivity())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add query all packages permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```